# Probability of choosing a subset of elements where each element has a different probability

Tags: probability, statistics, closed-form

I am trying to write a C++ program to do this but nobody on Stackoverflow can seem to help me so I thought I'd try to do it myself with some help from you guys.

My post on Stackoverflow can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727196/calculating-a-conditional-probability-that-is-similar-to-a-binomial-sum

My exact question would be, if I had 6 people where the probabilities of each person saying yes is given respectively by $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{7})$ respectively, what is the closed form summation form of the probability that 2 of them say yes?

I can calculate the probability of this directly by hand but I am having difficulty finding a closed form expression.

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for that. I have corrected it.

Comment: ok, now the difficult part... :)

Comment: Exactly two of them saying yes or at least two of them saying yes?

Comment: Exactly two of them saying yes. I should add that my goal is to generalize this to exactly $n$ of them saying yes.

Comment: A program would be used to deductively understand this. Otherwise you'd just have an equation and a program would be meaningless. Here's a program (in C#, because I forgot how to program in C++, haha): https://ideone.com/UWuSQ9 1 million trials, approximately 32.22%.

Comment: Nice! I didn't think of that. It would take a little more time if I were to test a large number of people with an arbitrary number of successes but definitely doable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first generalize, so we don't have to deal with actual numbers. I assume the numbers in your question are just examples, and not the actual numbers you want to use.

Let us say you have $n$ persons. Let the probability that person $i$ says yes be $p_i$. E.g., the probability of person 1 saying yes is $p_1$. Of course, it must follow that the probability of person $i$ saying no is $1 - p_i$. We want to know the probability of exactly $k$ people saying yes.

We can describe all scenarios by a sequence of zeros and ones, where the $i$:th digit is zero if person $i$ says no and one if person $i$ says yes.

E.g., if we have three persons and person 1 says yes, person 2 says no and person 3 says yes, this can be described as the configuration $(1,0,1)$ or ("yes", "no", "yes"). The probability of the configuration $(1,0,1)$ happening in this case is $p_1(1-p_2)p_3$.

Thus, in general, if we are given a configuration $\bar x = (x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$, where as before $x_i$ is either 0 or 1, we can easily compute the probability of this configuration happening. Let the probability of a configuration $\bar x$ be $P(\bar x)$.

Now, mathematically we can define the function $l(\bar x) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ to be the number of ones in the configuration $\bar x$ and give the solution:
$$p(\textrm{exactly $n$ people say yes}) = \sum_{\bar x: l(\bar x) = k} P(\bar x)$$
i.e., we sum the probabilities of the configurations where we have exactly $k$ ones.

Programmatically, we can use a divide-and-conquer approach. Let us say we want to know the probability of exactly $k$ people saying yes. The first person can say either yes or no (unless $p_1 = 1$). The same for the second person, and so on. Also, if $n-k$ persons have said no, the only way $k$ persons will say yes is if the remaining persons say yes, so in this case we can just compute $p_{n-k}p_{n-k+1}\cdots p_n$.

This can be expressed in code (general function but with your example as example):

```
#include <iostream>

double probability(double*,unsigned int,unsigned int);

int main()
{
    double yesprobs[6] = {1.0/2.0,1.0/3.0,1.0/4.0,1.0/5.0,1.0/6.0,1.0/7.0};
    double p = probability(yesprobs,6,2);
    std::cout << "The probability of exactly 2 people saying yes is: " << p << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

double probability(double* yesprobabilities, unsigned int numberOfPeople, unsigned int yesNumber)
{
    double kprobability = 0;
    // Not enough people!
    if(numberOfPeople < yesNumber)
    {
        kprobability = 0;
    }
    // n == k, the only way k people will say yes is if all the remaining people say yes.
    else if(numberOfPeople == yesNumber)
    {
        kprobability = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; ++i)
        {
            kprobability = kprobability * yesprobabilities[i];
        }
    }
    else if(yesprobabilities[0] == 1)
    {
        kprobability += probability(&yesprobabilities[1],numberOfPeople-1,yesNumber-1);
    }
    else
    {
        // The first person says yes, k - 1 of the other persons have to say yes.
        kprobability += yesprobabilities[0] * probability(&yesprobabilities[1],numberOfPeople-1,yesNumber-1);
        // The first person says no, k of the other persons have to say yes.
        kprobability += (1 - yesprobabilities[0]) * probability(&yesprobabilities[1],numberOfPeople-1,yesNumber);
    }
    return kprobability;
}
```

## Special case: $p_1 = p_2 = \dots = p_n$

In the special case where all the probabilities are the same $p_1 = p_2 = \dots = p_n$ (and independent of each other) we can call the probability that a person answers yes just $p$.

In this case we have a sequence of [Bernoulli trials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial), which are well-studied in probability theory. The probability of exactly $k$ successes (people answering yes) is:
$$\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$
where $\binom{n}{k}$ is a [binomial coefficient.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the answers are independent, you are looking for the coefficient of $x^2$ in the expansion of 
$$(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)(x+5)(x+6)/7!$$

which expands to $$({x}^{6}+21\,{x}^{5}+175\,{x}^{4}+735\,{x}^{3}+1624\,{x}^{2}+1764\,x+720)/5040$$

so giving a probability of two yeses of $\frac{1624}{5040}=\frac{29}{90}\approx 0.3222$ and you could find the probabilities of other numbers of yeses a similar way by looking at the other coefficients.

You really need a computer algebra system for questions like this.

Comment: Hmm. I have never seen this way of looking at it before. Can you refer me to literature that can tell me more about this? Also you don't think that it would be efficient for me to do this in C++? C++ is the programming language I am most familiar with so thats why I chose it but I can learn something else if it will be more efficient.

Comment: The method uses [probability generating functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function).  An example of a CAS is [Maxima](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_%28software%29) where the code `expand(product((x+k)/(k+1), k, 1, 6))` will give you the expansion.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}p=&\sum_{2\le i<j\le7}\frac1i\frac1j\prod_{2\le k\le 7\atop k\notin\{i,j\}}\left(1-\frac1k\right)\\&=\prod_{k=2}^7\left(1-\frac1k\right)\cdot \sum _{i=2}^6\frac{\frac1i}{1-\frac1i}\sum_{j=i+1}^7\frac{\frac1j}{1-\frac1j}\\ &=\prod_{k=2}^7\left(1-\frac1k\right)\cdot \sum _{i=2}^6\frac{1}{i-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^7\frac{1}{j-1}\end{align}$$

Comment: What does the big pi mean? Can you tell me what to Google? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p_i$ be the probability of person $i$ saying yes, and let $q_k$ be the probability of exactly $k$ out of $n$ persons saying yes. Then,

$$
q_k = \left[\prod_{i=1}^n(1-p_i + p_ix)\right]_k,
$$
where $[f(x)]_k$ is the coefficient of $x^k$ in the series expansion of  $f(x)$.

In your question, $p_i = \frac{1}{i}$, and $k=2$. So,

$$
q_2 = \left[\prod_{i=2}^{n+1}\left(1-\frac{1}{i} + \frac{x}{i}\right)\right]_2.
$$

One can find $q_2$ by taking the second derivate of the product with respect to $x$ and setting $x=0$, which gives
\begin{align*}
q_2 &= \sum_j\frac{1}{j}\sum_{i\neq j}\frac{1}{i}\prod_{l\neq i,j}\left(1-\frac{1}{l}\right)
&=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{j=2}^{n+1}\sum_{i=2,i\neq j}^{n+1}\frac{1}{(i-1)(j-1)}.
\end{align*}